# Rest API: Consumer is not authorized to access Magento_Sales::sales

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I am creating an Invoice through Magento REST API with the below request:

```
POST "https://<magento-domain>/mg2/rest/V1/order/9/invoice"
```

Request Headers:

```
{
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer jnsptpdgsvmk5mrbctisi3e0yml7k6iu"
}
```

Request Body:

```
{
    "capture": true,
    "order_id": 9,
    "items": [{
        "order_item_id": 33,
        "qty": 3,
        "extension_attributes": {}
    }],
    "notify": true,
    "appendComment": true,
    "comment": {
        "extension_attributes": {},
        "comment": "Invoice#: 22",
        "is_visible_on_front": 0
    },
    "arguments": {
        "extension_attributes": {}
    }
}
```

But I consistently get this error:

```
{
    "message": "Consumer is not authorized to access %resources",
    "parameters": {
        "resources": "Magento_Sales::sales"
    }
}
```

I am certain that the token I use works, because I am able to search orders and customers using the same token.  The token is automatically renewed when I get a 401 error code in the response.

Also, the user I set up in Magento is an Administrator, which (I believe) has a full access on all objects (Sales Orders, Invoice, Shipments, etc.).

I have already configured the Integrations as well.  So I am not sure what else I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with the **Admin User Token Authentication** and 
with the POST Method pass values like these:

```
{
  "capture": true,
  "items": [
    {
      "extension_attributes": {},
      "order_item_id": xxx,
      "qty": xxx
    }
  ],
  "notify": true,
  "appendComment": true,
  "comment": {
    "extension_attributes": {},
    "comment": "string",
    "is_visible_on_front": 0
  },
  "arguments": {
    "extension_attributes": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't see any difference from the original JSON that I post.